# Ctrl + Left mouse Click (multiple selection) in mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, keyevent

I am going to use `Ctrl` + `Left-mouse` Click to multiple select object using javascript/jquery.

Below is what I used with jQuery, I test in `windows' chrome` it is fine and can be used to multiple selection, however, when I use `Mac Sarifa` to open the page and do the multiple selection, it comes some problems:
When I hold down `control` Key and click an object I what to select, it will come out a `contextmenu`.(It seems `Mac` has this default set, just like right click in `windows`), however, I do not want this menu show, I just want it can behave like windows, how can I do? Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

```
 $(document).bind('keydown', function (e){

        if(e.keyCode === 17)//Ctrl
        {
            _this.Ctrl = true;
        }
    });
 $(document).bind('keyup', function (e)
    {
        if(e.which === 17)//Ctrl
        {
            _this.Ctrl = false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In Mac OSX the appropriate way to implement multiple selection is with the CMD key. It works like this in all native apps and IMO it should work the same way in the browser. What I would suggest you to check for the key in the mouse event handler instead of storing the key on keydown and reseting it on keyup like this:

```
function isMac() {
    return navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac OS X') != -1;
}

$(document).bind('mousedown', function (e) {
    if (isMac() && e.metaKey || !isMac() && e.ctrlKey) {
        // Multiple selection
    }
});
```

The implementation of isMac is taken from here - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/test-mac-pc-javascript/.

Comment: for me the simple version `e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey` also seems to work fine

Comment: only problem: as the mac also has a ctrl key you might not want to attach your handler to that key on a mac.

Comment: I do agree with @Jakob here - if we take either of them, both CTRL and CMD keys will do the same on the Mac. Even worse - this will capture the Windows key on Windows, which is definitely the desired result here. Usually the CMD key substitutes for CTRL on Windows and Linux. That's why I suggested the more complicated code.